# Dropdown focusout not working on descendant elements as expected

Tags: jquery, dropdown, jquery-focusout

I'm aware this is a common question but none of the answers I've seen solve my problem, apologies if I have missed one and this can be removed/marked as duplicate obviously...

**Markup**

```
<div class="has-dropdown">
    <button class="js-dropdown-trigger">
        Dropdown
    </button>

    <div class="dropdown">
        <div class="dropdown__item">
            Some random text with a <a href="#" class="stop-propagation">link</a> in it.
        </div>
        <div class="dropdown__divider"></div>
        <div class="dropdown__item">
            <a href="#">Item One</a>
        </div>
        <div class="dropdown__item">
            <a href="#">Item Two</a>
        </div>
        <div class="dropdown__item">
            <a href="#">Item Three</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Script**

```
$('.has-dropdown').off().on('click', '.js-dropdown-trigger', (event) => {
    const $dropdown = $(event.currentTarget).next('.dropdown');

    if (!$dropdown.hasClass('is-active')) {
        $dropdown.addClass('is-active');
    } else {
        $dropdown.removeClass('is-active');
    }
});

$('.has-dropdown').on('focusout', (event) => {
    const $dropdown = $(event.currentTarget).children('.dropdown');

    $dropdown.removeClass('is-active');
});
```

**Styling**

```
.has-dropdown {
    display: inline-flex;
    position: relative;
}

.dropdown {
    background-color: #eee;
    border: 1px solid #999;
    display: none;
    flex-direction: column;
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    left: 0;
    width: 300px;
    margin-top: 5px;
}

.dropdown.is-active {
    display: flex;
}

.dropdown__item {
    padding: 10px;
}

.dropdown__divider {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #999;
}
```

**Fiddle**

http://jsfiddle.net/joemottershaw/3yzadmek/

It's unbelievably simple, clicking the `js-dropdown-trigger` toggles the `is-active` dropdown class fine, clicking outside the `has-dropdown` container removes the `is-active` dropdown class too.

Except, what I expected to happen is focusing on a descendant element (either click or tab) of the `has-dropdown` element would mean that the `focusout` event handler shouldn't be triggered as you are still focused on a descendant element of the `has-dropdown` container.

> The `focusout` event is sent to an element when it, **or any element
>   inside of it**, loses focus. This is distinct from the blur event in
>   that it supports detecting the **loss of focus on descendant elements**

I know I could remove the `focusout` event handler and use something like:

```
$(document).on('click', (event) =>{
    const $dropdownContainer = $('.has-dropdown');

    if (!$dropdownContainer.is(event.target) && $dropdownContainer.has(event.target).length === 0) {
        $dropdownContainer.find('.dropdown').removeClass('is-active');
    }
});
```

This works, but if you were to click on the trigger and then tab through the links, when you tab past the last link, the dropdown will still be visible. Just struggling to find the best solution to keep the accessibility side of things.

I want to stick to the `focusout` method if at all possible.

**Updated based on [darshanags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51765288/dropdown-focusout-not-working-on-descendant-elements-as-expected/51821435#51821435) answer**

Although the updated script works for single elements, adding other elements to the `body` causes `focusout` not to work as intended anymore. I think this is because of the `if` statement seems to be true even when focus is applied to any element after the `has-dropdown` container, not just descendants? Cause if you are to update the HTML and add more focusable elements such as an input after the dropdown. When tabbing from the last focusable element from within the `has-dropdown` container to the input, the dropdown stays active. It only works if the dropdown is the last element in the DOM and only triggers when focus is lost on the DOM entirely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're almost there with your code - but I believe that there needs to be a bit more clarity of how `focusout` works with natively non-focusable elements (i.e: div, p) and their descendants which could be focusable elements (inputs, anchors).

When a container is bound to the `focusout` event which contains focusable elements, it's `focusout` event is triggered **each time** any of it's focusable child elements loses focus - this might be by keyboard navigation or by clicking on another child element or on the container itself. I've setup a fiddle that demonstrates this: https://jsfiddle.net/darshanags/v5gk2cz8/ - console messages are sent out each time the container gains or loses focus.

**Q: So, why does the menu hide itself in the example given in the question?**

**A:** The menu becomes visible when you click on the button, clicking on the button makes the button gain focus on itself. But once you click on the menu or an anchor inside the menu element, the button loses focus - this in turn triggers the 'focusout' event of the parent element and causes the menu to hide itself. This happens because the `focusout` event supports event bubbling.

**Q: How do we get around this?**

**A1.1: We make the parent element focusable by giving it a tabindex:**

```
<div class="has-dropdown" tabindex="0">
```

This addresses a couple of important things:

1. Gives the `div` element a focus outline - this in turn enhances accessibility of the element.
2. Helps click events register focus-related events on the `div` element - in this example, that would `focusout`. If the `tabindex` was omitted we would need to add additional JavaScript to compensate for the lost functionality.

**A1.2: Within the `focusout` event handler, we check if the element which gains focus is a descendant of the parent element, if it is, we don't remove the `is-active` class from the menu.**

**Complete example code:**

```js
$('.has-dropdown').off().on('click', '.js-dropdown-trigger', (event) => {
  const $dropdown = $(event.currentTarget).next('.dropdown');

  if (!$dropdown.hasClass('is-active')) {
    $dropdown.addClass('is-active');
  } else {
    $dropdown.removeClass('is-active');
  }
});

$('.has-dropdown').on('focusout', function(event) {
  const $reltarget = $(event.relatedTarget);
  const $currenttarget = $(event.currentTarget);
  const $dropdown = $currenttarget.children('.dropdown');

  // remove 'is-active' class only if the element
  // that is gaining focus is not a child of the parent.
  // parent = div.has-dropdown
  if (!$reltarget.closest('.has-dropdown').is($currenttarget)) {
    $dropdown.removeClass('is-active');
  }

});
```

```css
.has-dropdown {
  display: inline-flex;
  position: relative;
}

.dropdown {
  background-color: #eee;
  border: 1px solid #999;
  display: none;
  flex-direction: column;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  width: 300px;
  margin-top: 5px;
}

.dropdown.is-active {
  display: flex;
}

.dropdown__item {
  padding: 10px;
}

.dropdown__divider {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #999;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="has-dropdown" tabindex="0">
  <button class="js-dropdown-trigger">
        Dropdown
    </button>

  <div class="dropdown">
    <div class="dropdown__item">
      Some random text with a <a href="#" class="stop-propagation">link</a> in it.
    </div>
    <div class="dropdown__divider"></div>
    <div class="dropdown__item">
      <a href="#">Item One</a>
    </div>
    <div class="dropdown__item">
      <a href="#">Item Two</a>
    </div>
    <div class="dropdown__item">
      <a href="#">Item Three</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="has-dropdown" tabindex="0">
  <button class="js-dropdown-trigger">
        Dropdown
    </button>

  <div class="dropdown">
    <div class="dropdown__item">
      Some random text with a <a href="#" class="stop-propagation">link</a> in it.
    </div>
    <div class="dropdown__divider"></div>
    <div class="dropdown__item">
      <a href="#">Item One</a>
    </div>
    <div class="dropdown__item">
      <a href="#">Item Two</a>
    </div>
    <div class="dropdown__item">
      <a href="#">Item Three</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<input name="tf" type="text"/>
```

I've forked the original fiddle and modified it to show this in action. You may find the modified fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/darshanags/60jnusvk/.

**Other helpful information:**

I use `event.relatedTarget` to determine the element which gains focus every time the `focusout` event is triggered. More information on `event.relatedTarget` can be found here: https://api.jquery.com/event.relatedTarget/.

**Update**

I've refactored some of my original code, it's much simpler now: http://jsfiddle.net/darshanags/60jnusvk/24/. I will leave this fiddle and the original for reference.

Comment: I wasn't aware that `focusout` was called every time like that! This is a good step in the right direction though, so thank you for that! However, it only works if it's the only element within the body, I'll update my answer with an explanation now.

Comment: I've changed the `if` statement in the `focusout` event handler to the following: `if (!$(event.currentTarget).has(event.relatedTarget).length) { // Hide }}`. I believe this is working now and I think you can even remove the `tabindex` attribute and it works? http://jsfiddle.net/joemottershaw/scnx4od9/ If you think it is too, if you could update your answer with the new `if` statement and I'll mark it as correct with the bounty!

Comment: @Joe, I'm looking at your modified fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/joemottershaw/scnx4od9/. The dropdown menus work fine when I tab through the items using the keyboard but if I click anywhere else in the menu, it closes it - I don't think that is the desired behavior? I'm using firefox

Comment: Ah you would be right, that's not the desired behaviour either. Do you see what I mean about your `if` statement keeping the dropdown active when there are other elements on the page though? Maybe it needs a combination of both if statements, one to keep it open if clicked inside `has-dropdown` and also if a `has-dropdown` descendant is focused?

Comment: I added another check in my fiddle to see if we are on the same menu - http://jsfiddle.net/darshanags/60jnusvk/20/. I believe this satisfies the criteria in your original post and multiple menus.

Comment: This is fine if there are only dropdowns on the page, as I mentioned previously, if you were to add an input after the 2 dropdowns, when you focus from the last dropdown to the input, the dropdown still stays active? Also, isn't `&& $currenttarget.hasClass('has-dropdown')` always going to be `has-dropdown` as it **is** the current target?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/joemottershaw/r5nt2epc/ I think this is now working?

Comment: Yes, your fiddle works for me. But I've come up with a simpler bit of code, minus most of the checks that I implemented earlier. New fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/darshanags/60jnusvk/24/

Comment: Perfect, if you could update your answer with the latest code just in case the fiddle ever gets deleted or goes down etc. I'll mark as the correct answer and award the bounty, I appreciate the on going help, thank you :)

Comment: No problem - I've updated my answer. And I've also expanded on why I'm using `tabindex` on the div element(s).